# Why is codeblocks not respecting the breakpoints?

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks, breakpoints

I execute with debugger this code in codeblocks but the breakpoints are not respected. Why is this? The problem persists if I change the location of the breakpoint. When running the script with the default Codeblocks makefile everything debiggs ok. When changing to the makefile below the debugger sees the breakpoints only when dleting the "typedef unsigned char byte;".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char byte;
int main(const int argc, const char *const argv[])
{

return 0;
}
```

I use this makefile:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror
LDFLAGS =  -lgmp -lsodium -lssl -lcrypto -lgmpxx
SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp )
HDR = $(wildcard *.h )
OBJ = $(SRC) $(SRC :.cpp =.o )
all : Release
Debug : CXXFLAGS +=-g
Debug : test
Release : test
test : $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
%.o : %.cpp $(HDR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
clean :
    rm -f $(OBJ) test
```

The code runs without errors, only that I can't use the debugger.
Should I add in the makefile sth. about typedef command?

Comment: Did you forget to recompile the code, after changing something, and try to debug it?

Comment: Are you debugging with symbols on (-g) and optimizations disabled (-O0)?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius At least according to the message it rebuilt before running/attaching.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I _suspected_ the same, but just to avoid suspicions, I asked for the OP, to confirm, that everything is rebuilt, since it is the most common reason why debugger might refuse to enable breakpoints.

Comment: Where can I set this options "symbols on (-g) and optimizations disabled (-O0)"? Yes, the project has been rebuilt. I also deleted the cpp file and created a new one

Comment: Those also go into `CXXFLAGS`. However, you can see that in Debug mode, `-g` is already added to `CXXFLAGS`. On which line exactly are you putting the break points?

Comment: @user11903678, Right click on project, go to Build Options and in "Other Compiler Options", I think you can put it there.

Comment: Like CXXFLAGS = -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror  -g -O0 ?

Comment: Yes (although you will then affect both Release and Debug builds).

Comment: @user11903678, it should be `-g3 -O0`

Comment: I changed it and nothing happened. For what stands the -g3?

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. Now I updated the code to a shorter one and the question to a more precise one. I would appreciate your opinion.